# Gparted re-partitioning on a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, gparted

[image]

Hi,
Above is my gparted config, I want to move 100GB from etc!!! (sda3) to my ntfs partition (sda4). However the unallocated space comes to the left of the windows partition. If I subsequently resize to the left I come up with a warning that says boot would fail (I have currently a 16.04 and Windows 10 dual boot setup).

Is it safe to do this or would it end up in problems? Is there any other way of accomplishing this? Please do help.

The reason I want to do this is my steam library on ntfs is running out of space and I need to do something about it :(

Comment: The boot code for both Windows and GNU/Linux can be restored if it fails to work after resizing/moving partitions.  See [GParted FAQ for Restoring Window Boot](http://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-14), [Fixing GRUB boot Problem](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem), or search the Internet for other resources for restoring the ability to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First boot into Ubuntu and resize `sda3`. Leave the new unallocated space as is and restart the computer.Now boot into Windows and increase the size of`sda4` from within Windows. A restart may be required again.

Edit Windows-partitions only with Windows-tools, and Ubuntu-partitions only with Linux-tools!

Comment: In windows do I use disk management or is there some other tool? And there would be no boot problems like gparted warned me about.......?

Comment: I couldn't use disk management as the unallocated space was to the left , so I installed ease us partition manager and got it done. Subsequent boot was very slow but after I performed an defragment/optimisation it's all fine now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How do mark this as solved?

Comment: There is a mark left to the answer. Easus works nice and reliable. For defragmenting I use almost Ultradefrag, it's free and open source, super fast. But important to have some free space in the partition (min. 30%). Also always good to run chkdsk before defragmenting...

Comment: Thanks for all the help man, will do the chkdsk here on out :)